# You can't use pointer arithmetic on void pointers, so how do arrays of void pointers work?

Tags: c++, arrays, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

From reading tutorials, my understanding is that behind the scenes the operator([]) does the same thing as pointer arithmetic.

[Learncpp](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-8a-pointer-arithmetic-and-array-indexing/) has the following to say "It turns out that when the compiler sees the subscript operator ([]), it actually translates that into a pointer addition and dereference!".

[Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays) then says this "A variable declared as an array of some type acts as a pointer to that type. When used by itself, it points to the first element of the array."

Then after reading about void pointers, I was curious to know how would an array of them work? I imagine that my understanding of something must be wrong.

For an example the following two should be identical.

a)

```
void* array[5];
array[1] = nullptr;
```

b)

```
void* array[5];
*(array + 1) = nullptr;
```

Comment: Remember that arrays decays to pointers to their first element. That is, `array` decays to `&array[0]`. And that decayed pointer has the type `void**` which you *can* do pointer arithmetic on.

Comment: what is your question? the size of a void pointer is known (architecture specific though....). e.g. 32bit. Thus *(array +1)  will actually add 4bytes (size of each element if sizeof(void*) is 4) to the base address.

Comment: My question was, how does the operator([]) work with since there seemed to be a contradiction, but the above comment cleared that up. In fact I'd like him to post that as the answer, so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of pointers is basically just `**` - `void**` in your case.

You know the size of `void*` as it's just another pointer.